# This website contains unencrypted elements?

Tags: encryption, ssl, domain-security

I purchased a SSL certificate for my website and it is displaying a warning icon and warning message.

[image]

> This website does not supply identity information.
>
> The connection to this website is not fully secure because it contains
>   unencrypted elements (such as images) or the encryption is not strong
>   enough.

How do I know which it is and how do I ensure all the elements are encrypted? I'm guessing the images must use "https" if they are not. But I'm using WordPress for the blog so would I have to go through all of the WordPress source code to switch them to https? Is there a redirect option at my hosting company that lets me redirect http to https calls?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @nKn I went to Settings > General and changed the last two values "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" to use "https://" instead of "http://" 
[image]

Now I see a secure website padlock:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your cert, basically it says that there indeed are some links in your site to the HTTP protocol (`http://...`). It's easy to find out which is it, just open up the source code and look for some `http:` link there.

If you're using WordPress, make sure you change the URL of your site in the admin Dashboard from `http://...` to `https://...`. If that should not be enough, look at [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) which seems to fix the rewriting (careful, it says it might be deprecated because it hasn't been updated for a long time, I haven't tried it).

Also, [this](http://designmodo.com/wordpress-https/) might help though you already have configured your SSL cert. Go directly to the `Configuring WordPress for SSL/HTTPS` section.